# Maths ratios in Python

Tags: python, math

I wrote this a year ago, and while it serves its purpose, I wondered if someone much cleverer than me could suggest ways to improve its efficiency.

```
def tempcolor(mintemp=0,maxtemp=32,mincolor=44000,maxcolor=3200,ctemp=10,c=0):
    tempdiff=(mincolor-maxcolor) / (maxtemp-mintemp)
    ccolor=(ctemp-mintemp) * tempdiff
    ctouse=(mincolor-ccolor)
    #print ctouse
    return ctouse;
```

There's a range of numbers (mintemp to maxtemp). When ctouse is called, we calculate the ratio, then apply that same ratio to the other range of numbers (mincolor and maxcolor).

I'm using it in another script, and just wondered if anyone had any advice on making it neater. Or more accurate!

Thanks

Will

Comment: If you have code that is already working and you want to make it more efficient or nicer looking, try asking on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You should be taking the ratio in the first calculation using **floats**.  It depends on your version of Python, etc, but be sure you're doing this calculation using floats.

Comment: In your question you say "more accurate".  Could you please give an example case where the result is not accurate enough.

Comment: Are you sure the relationship is actually linear? What units are you using? Seeing 32 as a temperature makes me think it might be Fahrenheit. What is color measured in? Kelvin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you rarely or never change the given values for mintemp, maxtemp, mincolor, maxcolor.

The only efficiency improvement I can see would be to precalculate the ratio - something like

```
def make_linear_interpolator(x0, x1, y0, y1):
    """
    Return a function to convert x in (x0..x1) to y in (y0..y1)
    """
    dy_dx = (y1 - y0) / float(x1 - x0)
    def y(x):
        return y0 + (x - x0) * dy_dx
    return y

color_to_temp = make_linear_interpolator(0, 32, 44000, 3200)

color_to_temp(10)    # => 32150.0
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help and apologies for such a stupid question - I suppose, if anything, I'm relieved that it works and can't really be improved...though Hugh's option is probably superior!